# Unique hardware ID in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, unique, hardware-id

Mac OS X development is a fairly new animal for me, and I'm in the process of porting over some software. For software licensing and registration I need to be able to generate some kind of hardware ID. It doesn't have to be anything fancy; Ethernet MAC address, hard drive serial, CPU serial, something like that.

I've got it covered on Windows, but I haven't a clue on Mac. Any idea of what I need to do, or where I can go for information on this would be great!

Edit:

For anybody else that is interested in this, this is the code I ended up using with Qt's QProcess class:

```
QProcess proc;

QStringList args;
args << "-c" << "ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice |  awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { print $3; }'";
proc.start( "/bin/bash", args );
proc.waitForFinished();

QString uID = proc.readAll();
```

Note: I'm using C++.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this Terminal command:

```
ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, line, "\""); printf("%s\n", line[4]); }'
```

From [here](http://www.jaharmi.com/2008/03/15/get_uuid_for_mac_with_ioreg)

Here is that command wrapped in Cocoa (which could probably be made a bit cleaner):

```
NSArray * args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-rd1", @"-c", @"IOPlatformExpertDevice", @"|", @"grep", @"model", nil];
NSTask * task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/sbin/ioreg"];
[task setArguments:args];

NSPipe * pipe = [NSPipe new];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
[task launch];

NSArray * args2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, line, \"\\\"\"); printf(\"%s\\n\", line[4]); }", nil];
NSTask * task2 = [NSTask new];
[task2 setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/awk"];
[task2 setArguments:args2];

NSPipe * pipe2 = [NSPipe new];
[task2 setStandardInput:pipe];
[task2 setStandardOutput:pipe2];
NSFileHandle * fileHandle2 = [pipe2 fileHandleForReading];
[task2 launch];

NSData * data = [fileHandle2 readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString * uuid = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the way that works the best. The System Profiler output seems to vary on different systems so makes me fear a flood of support calls not being able to register the software.

Comment: This technique is easy to crack, though — just replace `/usr/sbin/ioreg` with a script that returns a known-good UUID (instead of a machine-specific UUID).  Directly calling into the system libraries (@yairchu's answer, for example), will make cracking a little less trivial.

Comment: @smokris otherwise is this equivalent to IORegistryEntryFromPath?

Answer (score 42):

For C/C++:

```
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

void get_platform_uuid(char * buf, int bufSize) {
    io_registry_entry_t ioRegistryRoot = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/");
    CFStringRef uuidCf = (CFStringRef) IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(ioRegistryRoot, CFSTR(kIOPlatformUUIDKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    IOObjectRelease(ioRegistryRoot);
    CFStringGetCString(uuidCf, buf, bufSize, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
    CFRelease(uuidCf);    
}
```

Comment: This worked for me with XCode 5.1 and Mac OS X 10.8.5

Comment: can this function return the same UUID even mac version upgraded in future? . (let's assume this function will work in future mac version now )

Comment: Would be an interesting answer but you did not specify the needed #includes ! Can you edit it to add them please ?

Comment: @Elena Sure thing. Added the include, but do note that in my specific codebase this hasn't been used since 2018 so I can't assure whether this still work

Comment: Did not work for me on Apple silicon with macOS 14.2.1. Builds and runs but buffer comes back empty.

Answer (score 12):

Why not try `gethostuuid()`? Here's the documentation from the Mac OS X System Calls Manual:

NAME:

```
 gethostuuid -- return a unique identifier for the current machine
```

SYNOPSIS:

```
 #include <unistd.h>

 int gethostuuid(uuid_t id, const struct timespec *wait);
```

DESCRIPTION:

> The gethostuuid() function returns a 16-byte uuid_t specified by id, that uniquely identifies the current machine.  Be aware that the hardware identifiers that gethostuuid() uses to generate the UUID can themselves be modified.
>
> The wait argument is a pointer to a struct timespec that specifies the maximum time to wait for the result.  Setting the tv_sec and tv_nsec fields to zero means to wait indefinitely until it completes.

RETURN VALUES:

> The gethostuuid() function returns zero on success or -1 on error.

ERRORS

> The gethostuuid() functions fails if:

```
 [EFAULT]           wait points to memory that is not a valid part of the
                    process address space.

 [EWOULDBLOCK]      The wait timeout expired before the UUID could be
                    obtained.
```

Comment: Apparently this isn't supported in Mac OS any longer.

Comment: On my Mac BigSur 11.3.1 this function is still available and returns the same value as get with the shell command `ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlaformExpertDevice` within `"IOPlatformUUID"`.

Answer (score 9):

This would be easier to answer if you told us what language you were using. The information is obtainable without any shell commands through the SystemConfiguration framework, and also through IOKit if you want to get your hands really dirty.

```
- (NSString*) getMACAddress: (BOOL)stripColons {
    NSMutableString         *macAddress         = nil;
    NSArray                 *allInterfaces      = (NSArray*)SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll();
    NSEnumerator            *interfaceWalker    = [allInterfaces objectEnumerator];
    SCNetworkInterfaceRef   curInterface        = nil;

    while ( curInterface = (SCNetworkInterfaceRef)[interfaceWalker nextObject] ) {
        if ( [(NSString*)SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(curInterface) isEqualToString:@"en0"] ) {
            macAddress = [[(NSString*)SCNetworkInterfaceGetHardwareAddressString(curInterface) mutableCopy] autorelease];

            if ( stripColons == YES ) {
                [macAddress replaceOccurrencesOfString: @":" withString: @"" options: NSLiteralSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, [macAddress length])];
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return [[macAddress copy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You're right I should have specified the language. I updated the question and tags. I am using C++ and the Qt framework for cross-platform development.

Comment: Then SCNetworkInterfaceGetHardwareAddressString will get it for you without forking another process to run a shell script.

Comment: macAddress assignment on line 12 requires an autorelease

Answer (score 7):

```
/*
g++ mac_uuid.cpp -framework CoreFoundation -lIOKit
*/


#include <iostream>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

using namespace std;

void get_platform_uuid(char * buf, int bufSize)
{
   io_registry_entry_t ioRegistryRoot = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/");
   CFStringRef uuidCf = (CFStringRef) IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(ioRegistryRoot, CFSTR(kIOPlatformUUIDKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
   IOObjectRelease(ioRegistryRoot);
   CFStringGetCString(uuidCf, buf, bufSize, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
   CFRelease(uuidCf);
}

int main()
{
   char buf[512] = "";
   get_platform_uuid(buf, sizeof(buf));
   cout << buf << endl;
}
```

Comment: `$ c++ mac_uuid.cpp -framework CoreFoundation -lIOKit` leads to: `ld: library not found for -lIOKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: `g++ mac_uuid.cpp -o mac_uuid -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit` works for me

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Btw do you know if it is possible to get the uuid as unformatted binary (the raw 16 bytes) ?

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
system_profiler | grep 'Serial Number (system)'
```

in a terminal returns what it likely a unique id. That works on my 10.5 box, I'm not sure what the correct string will be in other versions of OS X.

Comment: There are actually some Macs that have shipped without a serial number, so you shouldn't do anything that relies 100% on having a unique serial number available.

Comment: `system_profiler` will also sometimes take a while.  If you've got a disc in the DVD drive it'll spin up, for example.

Comment: I've seen some of that Mac's without Serial Number (and had problems with my software licensing), but UUID is always there. You should sick with UUID.

Comment: If you specify the correct datatype with `system_profiler`, it will speed it up significantly by only returning the information associated with that type. In this case, it would be `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType`

Answer (score 1):

As some people above have hinted, you can use a Terminal command to get a hardware ID.

I assume you want to do this in code however so I would take a look at the NSTask class in Cocoa. It basically lets you run terminal commands inside your application.

This code is an example of how to use NSTask in Cocoa. It sets up the environment to execute the "killall" command. It passes it the arguement "Finder".

It's the equivilent of running "killall Finder" on the command line, which will kill the Finder obviously.

```
NSTask *aTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *args = [NSMutableArray array];

[aTask setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/killall"];
[args addObject:[@"/Applications/Finder" lastPathComponent]];
[aTask setArguments:args];
[aTask launch];

[aTask release];
```

Comment: What's with the cast to `NSString*`, and why call `lastPathComponent`? That line is equivalent to `[args addObject:@"Finder"]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is equivalent and far simpler than the ioreg command.

`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/UUID/ { print $3 }`

Answer (score 0):

System Profiler (in Applications - Utilities) contains most of this kind of info.  It has your serial number and your mac address (no relation to Mac.  All computers have a mac address which is pretty much unique to every network card).