# Unique Identifier of a Mac?

Tags: cocoa, macos, uniqueidentifier

On an iPhone I can use

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

to get a string which identifies this device. Is there anything equal in OSX ? I didn't find anything. I just want to identify the Mac which started the application. Can you help me ?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933460/unique-hardware-id-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Have an up-vote and a Swift 2-updated answer. ;-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apple has a [technote](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1103.html) on uniquely identifying a mac. Here's a loosely modified version of the code Apple has posted in that technote... don't forget to link your project against `IOKit.framework` in order to build this:

```
#import <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

- (NSString *)serialNumber
{
    io_service_t    platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault,

    IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
    CFStringRef serialNumberAsCFString = NULL;

    if (platformExpert) {
        serialNumberAsCFString = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert,
                                                         CFSTR(kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey),
                                                             kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);
    }

    NSString *serialNumberAsNSString = nil;
    if (serialNumberAsCFString) {
        serialNumberAsNSString = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)serialNumberAsCFString];
        CFRelease(serialNumberAsCFString);
    }

    return serialNumberAsNSString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll try it out. I didn't work with the IOKit yet. But will take a look at it.

Comment: That's great! I don't really understand the code yet. But it gives me a serial number. Thank you!

Comment: This solution isn't working in 64-bit mode unfortunately. Maybe you know something about this issue ?

Comment: @KamilZieliński you need to import IOKit.framework most likely

Comment: Be aware that many times if a machine has been repaired (i.e. the motherboard replaced) then the machine will have NO serial number. You might want to consider falling back to the MAC address of a network interface.

Comment: Is this valid for app store?

Comment: @Jarret Would this violate any guidelines set by Apple(as of now) for app store submissions ?

Comment: Added a Swift 2 answer.

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 2 Answer**

This answer augments Jarret Hardie's 2011 answer. It's a Swift 2 String extension. I've added inline comments to explain what I did and why, since navigating whether or not an object needs to be released can be tricky here.

```
extension String {

    static func macSerialNumber() -> String {

        // Get the platform expert
        let platformExpert: io_service_t = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));

        // Get the serial number as a CFString ( actually as Unmanaged<AnyObject>! )
        let serialNumberAsCFString = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

        // Release the platform expert (we're responsible)
        IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);

        // Take the unretained value of the unmanaged-any-object 
        // (so we're not responsible for releasing it)
        // and pass it back as a String or, if it fails, an empty string
        return (serialNumberAsCFString.takeUnretainedValue() as? String) ?? ""

    }

}
```

Alternatively, the function could return `String?` and the last line could *not* return an empty string. That might make it easier to recognize the extreme situations where the serial number could not be retrieved (such as the repaired-Mac-motherboard scenario harrisg mentioned in his comment to Jerret's answer).

I also verified proper memory management with Instruments.

I hope someone finds it useful!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. Works perfectly after changing

```
serialNumberAsNSString = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)serialNumberAsCFString];
```

TO

```
serialNumberAsNSString = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString *)serialNumberAsCFString];
```

the __bridge is recommended by Xcode itself.