# Incorrect domain name in objective-c for mac machine

Tags: objective-c, macos, dns

I am trying to get the domain name of my macbook pro using following method.

```
NSString *name = [[NSHost currentHost] name];
```

It returns me the name like 'The-Special-MBP.local' but this is not consistent, It returns me some other string sometimes.

I am not getting why is this happening, the same function call returns two different values at different times.

Basically I need to indicate the different machines in network with some unique id or string hence I am reading the name from NSHost class but it gives different values for same machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ethernet connection. Please you are connected in same network

Comment: I am on Wifi.Which has single configured address

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique id for your MAC, you may refer the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868967/1987246