# Programmatically check state of do not disturb on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Using Objective-C, how can I programmatically check the state of the system "Do Not Disturb" setting on OS X? I'm fine with using hacks or private APIs since I don't need to submit to the Mac App Store.

Comment: Did you get any solution ? if so, then please post it, I badly need it.

Comment: I never found a solution, I gave up

Comment: This works for all usecases in swift https://github.com/sindresorhus/do-not-disturb

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419207/turn-do-not-disturb-on-or-off-in-an-applescript-app-macos-catalina/419215#419215

Answer (score 7):

You can (and should) simply use UserDefaults:

```
let theDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.notificationcenterui")
print(theDefaults?.bool(forKey: "doNotDisturb"))
```

For time-controlled switching you should check if the minute of the day lies between `dndStart` and `dndEnd`:

```
let theDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.notificationcenterui")
let theDate = Date()
let theCalendar = Calendar.current

let theHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: theDate)
let theMinute = calendar.component(.minute, from: theDate)
let theMinuteOfDay = Double(theHour * 60 + theMinute)

if theMinuteOfDay >= theDefaults.double(forKey: "dndStart") && 
    theMinuteOfDay <= theDefaults.double(forKey: "dndEnd") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It works for me in Catalina, too. You should probably check the keys `dndStart` and `dndEnd` for time-controlled switching.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, baffling, not working at all. Tried dndStart / dndEnd / doNotDisturb, also tried the `CFPreferencesCopyValue` variant to see if that gets me anything. Nothing. Yet, if I try this on terminal, it works. Could it be something to do with sandboxing?

Comment: If I print out the dictionaryRepresentation of the allocated NSUserDefaults, I can see dozens of keys / values but nothing to do with DND.

Comment: Yes, Sandboxing might definitely a problem.

Comment: I've verified that this only works if you remove the "App Sandbox" capability from your project's "Signing & Capabilities" settings. Unfortunately removing that capability also means that your app cannot be distributed on the App Store.

Comment: This no longer works in Big Sur. `last-analytics-stamp` is the only entry in `com.apple.notificationcenterui` regardless of DnD settings.

Comment: @Kornel have you found a solution for Big Sur?

Comment: @PauliusLiekis Nope. Big Oof.

Comment: @Kornel I eventually found a script that works, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69287975/217022 but otherwise the internet is full of solutions that do not :D

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69760) describes how to read and write the state of **Do Not Disturb** using the command line.

Note that the filename contains your Mac's **Hardware UUID**. For simplicity, it's a constant in the code below. You can figure it out using the built-in **System Information** app.
There are also different ways to get it programmatically, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114144/843549), which I haven’t tried yet.

Using **Swift**, the content of the **plist** file can be read as `NSDictionary` as follows:

```
import Foundation

// Get path to file
let uuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
let filepath = "~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.\(uuid).plist".stringByExpandingTildeInPath

// Load file as `NSDictionary`
if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filepath) {

    // Get state of Do Not Disturb
    let doNotDisturbState = dict["doNotDisturb"] as? Bool
    println(doNotDisturbState)
}
```

When I tested it, it sometimes took several seconds for the content of the **plist** file to be updated, hence you won't get the new state immediately after it changed.

Comment: Do you know what the necessary sandbox exceptions for this method would be?

Comment: You should never access user defaults by file directly, because macOS uses a service to manage. Thus, the file's content and the answer of `NSUserDefaults` `valueForKey` may differ.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, you can access the value like this:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"com.apple.notificationcenterui"];
BOOL dnd = [defaults boolForKey:@"doNotDisturb"];
```

Comment: This no longer works in Big Sur. `last-analytics-stamp` is the only entry in `com.apple.notificationcenterui` regardless of DnD settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.notificationcenterui")?.bool(forKey: "doNotDisturb")
```

Comment: it always returns false

Comment: There is difference between A) DND scheduled via Preferences>Notifications, B) DND turned on manually in the right-side notification area (scroll up to show the DND switch). The B) variant is probably detected correctly, but the A) variant is probably ignored.