# Objective-C: check state of do not disturb per application on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

MAC OS X has settings per application and you can turn on Do Not Disturb Mode just for a specific one: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2r0bji/do_not_disturb_mode_in_os_x_when_using_a_specific/

Also...there is a way to detect the DND mode set for the whole system, based on this: [Programmatically check state of do not disturb on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311482/programmatically-check-state-of-do-not-disturb-on-os-x/39095105)

But is there any API that would allow me to do a check per application and see if it has DND enabled or not?

Comment: There is no per application Do Not Disturb. The liked discussion doesn't even make that claim.

Answer (score 5):

There is **no per-app** Do Not Disturb in macOS.

The closest you're probably going get to this is retrieving the `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` method of `NSApplication`

This returns a `NSRemoteNotificationType` value, which contains a bitmask whose values indicate the types of push notifications that the app requested.

The possible values are:

> `NSRemoteNotificationTypeNone` - The app should not display a badge.
>   `NSRemoteNotificationTypeBadge` - The app should display a badge.
>   `NSRemoteNotificationTypeSound` - The app should play a sound.
>   `NSRemoteNotificationTypeAlert` - The app should display an alert.

This is only going to be useful for the current running app and you can get more info from the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428776-enabledremotenotificationtypes?language=objc)

**Another potential place to look**:

You can find the SQLite database that NotificationCenter uses at in following directory:
`getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR` + `/com.apple.notificationcenter/db`, however do be careful, as mine wasn't in `/db`, the latest version was in `/db2`

**Prior to Yosemite**, this file was located at `~/Library/Application\ Support/NotificationCenter/`

I haven't gone through this database so I can't tell you whether or not applicable settings reside here, but it's a good place to start looking.

If you're publishing your app on the App Store, you probably won't be able to use this method because of sandboxing, but it's worth a try either way.