# How can I dismiss/hide OSX notifications in XCUITests?

Tags: swift, macos, xctest, xcuitest

I have these notifications (on CI machine):

[image]

That "pollute" my screenshots of the app that I'm testing using `XCUITests`. How can I dismiss or hide them during the test?

I've seen some answers for iOS (like dragging on `XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")`), but the same things do not seem to work for Mac as springboard doesn't exists on Mac.

Comment: Can you just take window-only screenshots, instead?

Comment: No, it looks like `XCUIElement.screenshot` just takes a screenshot of everything on screen and then clips it to the target element.

Comment: Interesting, that's disappointing, given how good the usual window screenshotting capabilities of macOS are (e.g. you can screenshot a window that's partially occluded, with a transparent background, and still get a perfect shot of it). Would turning on do-not-disturb hide those notifications?

Comment: That's kinda what I'm trying to figure out - how to hide/dismiss those notifications as part of the test, i.e. in an automated way.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, have you tried turning on DND? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145487/how-to-enable-disable-do-not-disturb-from-shell-on-mavericks

Comment: How are you taking the screenshot? Can you share that code?

Comment: @Alexander thanks! it was the solution, I just had to find the script that works on Big Sur as most answers don't.

Comment: @Cristik `XCUIElement` implements `XCUIScreenshotProviding`, which has `screenshot` method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiscreenshotproviding/2897250-screenshot. You can also call it on `XCUIScreen` too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enable "Do Not Disturb" mode from the terminal as that hides all notifications even the ones that you received before enabling it.

I used this script:

```
brew install vitorgalvao/tiny-scripts/calm-notifications
calm-notifications on
```

Taken from this answer: https://github.com/sindresorhus/do-not-disturb/issues/9#issuecomment-765083970

There are plenty of other answers on how to enable the "Do Not Disturb" mode from terminal, but most of them do not work on OSX Big Sur.