How can I define my MacOS app's behaviour depending on the Focus Setting (Do Not Disturb)
I'm trying to define my MacOS app behaviour depending on if Do Not Disturb is enabled. If it is, my app will avoid opening new windows automatically or else it will open new windows resembling notifications.
I believe using the official Notifications API is the only way to integrate with Do Not Disturb - but is it also possible to check the status and specify my app's behaviour? I do not intend on changing the DoNotDisturb status within my app - I just want to respect it.
To me, focusFilterIntent seems more user defined - and not obtained from the sustem. Appreciate any help, thanks!
I've tried to use the focus status center as follows:
let focusStatus = try? await INFocusStatusCenter.default.focusStatus
but this doesn't seem to reflect the DoNotDisturb state. I've also tried following this older post (How to read do not disturb using applescript?)

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39095105/4069976 Seems a little whacky, but maybe gets the job done?
