# How to get a unique id of a Mac machine in 2018?

Tags: c#, macos, uniqueidentifier

Requirement: no apple developer account.

**I don't care about iOS devices.** Only a unique id of a Mac (iMac, Mac mini and Macbook) is needed.

I have used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944103/3427520) but it does't work any more on some latest Mac:

```
ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, line, "\""); printf("%s\n", line[4]); }'
```

**Why I think it doesn't work?**
I have got some feedbacks from my clients that this approach get some random number. And I have checked the IDs my server received: Yes, they are random numbers (maybe it is regenerated after the Mac restarts).

**So my question is:**
How to get an unique id of a Mac now **in 2018**? Approaches that doesn't demand writting Objective-C or C++ code are preferred.

I'm trying to get the ID in C#: Mono, Unity3D or Xamarin.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work any more", does it throw an error? Does it just return something non-unique?

Comment: Did you try any of the other approaches from there, and what language are you looking for? The code in the next answer down answer that goes via `SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll` shows a plain C interface in use, albeit wrapped up in Objective-C in that answer. There's no actual need to [toll-free] bridge the `CFArray`, etc, to Objective-C types, it's just easier for people who use that language. Is it C you were looking for?

Comment: I have got some feedbacks from my clients that this approach get some random number. And I have verfied the IDs I received in my server: Yes, they are random numbers. @AdamV

Comment: `NSTask` is not needed. You can parse IOReg directly with the APIs `IOServiceMatching`, `IOServiceGetMatchingService` and `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty` passing key `kIOPlatformUUIDKey` in the `IOKit` framework

Comment: @Tommy Thanks! The random number phenomenon doesn't happen on my Mac. So I haven't tried other approaches for now. I have updated the question: I'm trying to find a C# solution.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the tip. But that doesn't solve the problem. A new approach is needed.

Comment: Another downvote. WOW~  I'm not asking why it doesn't work. This problem only happens on some clients' computer. edited the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal.app you can get information via `system_profiler`, e.g. for a UUID:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/UUID/ {print $3}'
```

or the Macs serial number, which should not be randomized:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}'
```